# Build caffe wrong when input " make all "

Tags: caffe

**when I build the caffe in ubuntu 16.04 ( after "make all"), it displays as bellow**:

> AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a LD -o
>
> .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l
>   -lopencv_core
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Makefile:573: recipe  for target
>   '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5' failed
>
> make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5] Error 1

Comment: What did change in ur Makefile.Config file? Can u share ?

Comment: OK . I will make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have opencv installed on your system. Install opencv either from sources or with app-get install libopencv-dev.
If opencv libraries are already on your system (try locate libopencv_core to make sure), run:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/opencv/libs
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Can you pretty-build (run Q="" && make all) to see the full linker command?

Comment: what doe it mean "Q="""

Comment: @Beili - enable pretty build